# The method aspectOf is undefined

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I built a mailserver in java and I have been providedwith an ObserverProtocol written with AOP. I am using Eclipse with AspectJ plugin as required

I try to use static methods like aspectOf, who I as understand should be added at the weaving step

Eclipse can't seem to make it work as I always get the following error :

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method aspectOf() is undefined for the type ObserverProtocol    MailReaderBean.java /emailClent_test/src/emailserver    line 86 Java Problem

From what I understood by snooping around various websites, tutorials and documentation, it seems that my .aj files aren't being woven correctly

I tried compiling manually with ajc to no avail, and I tinkered with paths and settings and jars and libs in various ways, nothing seems to work and I can't seem to find a definitive guide or tutorial to setup things correctly

My aspect code :

```
package protocol;


import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public abstract aspect ObserverProtocol 
{

    protected interface Subject { }


    protected interface Observer { }

    private WeakHashMap perSubjectObservers;        

    protected List getObservers(Subject s) 
    {
        if (perSubjectObservers == null) 
        {
            perSubjectObservers = new WeakHashMap();
        }

        List observers = (List)perSubjectObservers.get(s);

        if ( observers == null ) 
        {
            observers = new LinkedList();
            perSubjectObservers.put(s, observers);
        }

        return observers;
    }       

    public void addObserver(Subject s, Observer o) 
    {
        getObservers(s).add(o);
    }       

    public void removeObserver(Subject s, Observer o) 
    {
        getObservers(s).remove(o);
    }

    protected abstract pointcut subjectChange(Subject s);

    after(Subject s): subjectChange(s) 
    {
        Iterator iter = getObservers(s).iterator();

        while ( iter.hasNext() ) 
        {
            updateObserver(s, ((Observer)iter.next()));
        }
    }       

    protected abstract void updateObserver(Subject s, Observer o);

    public static ObserverProtocol aspectOf() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this;
    }
}
```

Offending code in my java server

```
//Add observer Proxy for monitoring the subject MailServer.
ObserverProtocol.aspectOf().addObserver(this, proxy );
```

Is there any resources that could help me understand how weaving works and how to setup my build without resorting to Spring or Maven?

Comment: Please consider removing excessive comments when posting code; in general it's just noise that makes the code harder to think about.

Comment: I will try to decompile the class tonight when I get back home (also removed comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method (and `hasAspect()`) is added during weaving. If your aspect was built with `javac` rather than `ajc`, then it will not have these methods when jvm starts because the weaver hasn't yet run.

I recommend you read these documents:

- [Hello World (AspectJ)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Hello_World_%28AspectJ%29)
- [Getting Started with AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting.html)

Comment: I tried to manually compile with ajc in command line, but it's a fairly large project with quite a few packages and I wasn't able to do it properly. I'll try again as soon as possible

Comment: Turns out, my build was fine. This had nothing to do with the weaving at all, I was wrong somewhere else in my code. Thanks though